# Windows.Devices.PointOfService - WinRT only?

Tags: .net

Is Windows.Devices.PointOfService only in WinRT?

We are on .NET for Windows.

We want to use it, but it is not clear if it is in all .NET.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/bg182882.aspx

Where is the real story?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429024(v=winembedded.4).aspx

Comment: @HansPassant Even that site is not clear. It implies (from the URL, for example) to be discussing Windows Embedded, but the FAQ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee406171(v=winembedded.4).aspx says it can be used on regular Windows (but does not mention Win10, even though the article is dated 2017)  Not clear!

Comment: Just call Microsoft Sales, they'll answer all your questions.  Be sure to have a decent idea what hardware you are going to run this on or you still won't get far.

Comment: @HansPassant Call MS Sales RE an SDK? That is a new suggestion. (And no, I don't expect to do it, nor that they would have any clue beyond what we can read.)